# Aws::S3::Presigner presigned_url returns 403 forbidden with virtual_host

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to make a private object on a static website hosted S3 bucket which is accessible from a signed URL. Seems simple enough, however using the following code with `virtual_host` enabled seems to always result in a 403 Forbidden. If I disable `virtual_host` then it works as expected.

```
url = Aws::S3::Presigner.new.presigned_url(
    :get_object,
    :bucket => BUCKET,
    :key => KEY,
    :virtual_host => true
)

uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
resp = http.request(request)
puts resp.body
```

Is there a permissions/setting that is missing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

These are the reasons

1. Access Denied
2. Account issue

[image]